# Google Drive API Get File Does Not return Owner Filename or Properties

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API V3.

I have created a file using the code below:

```
Dictionary<string, string> prop = new Dictionary<string, string>();
prop.Add("Project1", "TestData");
var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
{
    Description = "ClassAwesome_Files",
    Name = "Project plan1234",
    CreatedTime = DateTime.Now,
    Properties = prop,
    MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"
};
var request = driveService.Files.Create(fileMetadata);
request.Fields = "id";
var file = request.Execute();
```

This code successfully creates the file, but when I try to get the file from `File.Id` I cannot get  filemetadata like Description,Properties etc...
I only get filemetadata like Id,Name and MimeType.

Here's the code I use to fetch the file:

```
// Create Drive API service.
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = service.Files.List();
listRequest.PageSize = 10;
listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name)";
IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> files = listRequest.Execute()
    .Files;
Console.WriteLine("Files:");
if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
{
    Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file = files.Where(x => x.Id == 
    MyFileId Which i created above code).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Can you please Help me How i get Properties and File Owner Name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is a commonly asked question. Set `listRequest.Fields="*"`

Comment: Thank you very much